# Which fragment will execute faster / generate fewer lines of code?  (C++ / JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, c++

Which of these is more efficient in terms of speed (number of lines of code generated).

```
var x=obj.mem;
x.do1();
x.do2();
```

or

```
obj.mem.do1();
obj.mem.do2();
```

I just wrote those in a generic pattern. Specifically, if I have to access a member( or a member of a member ) , is it better to assign the common part to a variable and then use that variable or to call it directly as shown in the second case.

I'm concerned mainly about C++ and JavaScript (if it matters).
Thank You.

EDIT->
PS.I did not ask a common answer. I understand that Javascript is an interpreter language while C++ is compiler based. The little knowledge I have of JavaScript is self taught and we learned C++ for 2 years at school (and that too Turbo C++) and the rest is again self taught. So, forgive me for the confusion. I was expecting a general result assuming that the constructs are valid and considering any possible variations. Anyway, my major doubts were cleared. Thanks.

Conclusion: JS is faster with local variables (though negligible) and C++ will probably optimise to get almost equal results.

Thank You for all the input.

Comment: -1 You cannot ask on a construct in two such unrelated languages. As a matter of fact, the meaning of the same code snippet (filling the blanks so that it actually compiles) might be completely different!

Comment: -1 For the same reasons as David - your code probably isn't valid C++ (unless you've #defined var) and if you did correct the first code sample it probably wouldn't have the same effect as the first.

Comment: -1 In C++, assuming some reasonable definition of `var`, the two code snippets have different semantics. It doesn't matter which is faster -- they do different things.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas @Joe Gauterin @Rob Adams    I disagree.  I think he should have asked for even more languages. Why not talk about the theory of it? And I don't think anyone suggested this was meant to be valid C++. JavaScript or just pseudocode is ok too.  There's no need to write out the same bit of code over and over in every language you know just to ask a question on SO.

Comment: @Buh Buh: The problem is that the code in question is not compatible with both languages, and the answer is *very* dependent on the language. I don't know Javascript, in Java where everything are references they are the same, in C# it depends on whether the object is a struct or class, in C++ it depends on the definition of `var` (that in c++ must be a declared type, but it could have a hidden reference, so it is still unanswerable...

Comment: @Buh -- I agree with you; it's okay for him to ask the question generically, or without language context. But the nature of his question implies that the two code snippers are semantically equivalent, and he is only interested in which goes faster. In languages (like JS and Python) where assignment modifies references they are equivalent. In languages (like C an C++) in which assignment copies data, they are not. It doesn't make sense to discuss the OP's question in the latter case, since his underlying premise is faulty.

Comment: Guys, these sound a lot like answers to me, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variables in JavaScript are faster because [The further into the chain, the slower the resolution](http://www.slideshare.net/nzakas/speed-up-your-javascript).

Comment: Take a look at slides 17 and 18.

Answer (score 7):

In JavaScript the first one is faster. You would think that there shouldn't be much difference, but I ran into this while developing Dreamweaver extensions (they use JavaScript) and there is a huge difference.

I advise you to avoid long chains.

Benchmarking:

```
var x = {y:{z:null}};
var start = (new Date).getTime();
for(var i=0;i<1000000;i++){
    x.y.z = i;
}
alert((new Date).getTime()-start);
```

vs.

```
var x = {y:{z:null}};
var start = (new Date).getTime();
var q = x.y;
for(var i=0;i<1000000;i++){
    q.z = i;
}
alert((new Date).getTime()-start);
```

The second one is about 10% faster in my Firefox. But keep in mind that this is a minimalist scenario. If you work with larger object and deeper levels the difference will probably go up.

And of course it does:

```
var x = {a:{b:{c:{d:{y:{z:null}}}}}};
var start = (new Date).getTime();
for(var i=0;i<1000000;i++){
    x.a.b.c.d.y.z = i;
}
alert((new Date).getTime()-start);
```

vs.

```
var x = {a:{b:{c:{d:{y:{z:null}}}}}};
var start = (new Date).getTime();
var q = x.a.b.c.d.y;
for(var i=0;i<1000000;i++){
    q.z = i;
}
alert((new Date).getTime()-start);
```

Is 30% enough for it not to be negligible?

Regards,
Alin

Comment: @Michael Kjörling Try the second set.

Comment: Are you sure that is a fair test? var q = x.a.b.c.d.y.z; q = 5; is not the same as x.a.b.c.d.y.z = 5;   Is it?

Comment: No Alin, 30% is not enough to be negligible. Normally a page doesn't set a value on an object 1000000 times. If you do, then optimize. But in normal situations: don't. @Buh Buh: it is the same, object elements are pass-by-reference in JS.

Comment: @nightcracker 1000000 was chosen to make the difference visible and as I said in the beginning of my answer I ran into this issue myself with real application code, but I won't post that here. All I will say is that the code was searching through DOM nodes.

Comment: @nightcracker -- `x.a.b.c.d.y.z = i;` changes the value of z.  These will end up z == 999999. `q = i;` does not change the value of z.  These will stay z == null.  The pass-by-reference bit is relevant for the question but ignored by this answer.

Comment: @Buh Bug You're right about the reference part and I corrected the code. But the numbers stay the same ;)

Comment: @Alin -- Yea that looks better now.  Big +1 from me.

Comment: Woops, what I said about pass-by-reference was BS, ignore it :)

Answer (score 4):

In C++, with the compiler optimiser turned on, they should both perform identically (at least on average).

Comment: Depends on the definition of `var`, is it a reference or a value, in the later case, not only it will be slower but it will have complete different semantics.

Comment: @David: good point: I would hope a pointer or reference would be used where sensible, but even in other cases the optimiser may well remove the copying if there's no side effects.

Answer (score 2):

At least in JavaScript, by assigning the property to a local variable, you avoid looking up `obj` in a potential high (like global) scope, which can be "slow".

The rule of thumb for JS is: If you have to access a non-local object more than once, make it local.

Same for nested properties. Instead of accessing `a.b.c.d.x` and `a.b.c.d.y`, it is better to assign `a.b.c.d` to a variable, if possible.

If you are interested in performance in general, have a look at the book [*High Performance JavaScript*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059680279X).

Answer (score 2):

In C++ any sub-decent compiler will optimize the difference away.

In Javascript the difference should be neglectible. Don't waste your time on stuff like that unless you are building a library to be used by millions like jQuery.

**EDIT**

Apparently some people don't understand what I mean with neglectible in the argument above. Yes, you can benchmark this stuff and see that it's 30% faster to create local variables. But `1.30 * 0.003` milliseconds is **not noticeable, thus neglectible**, unless it's executed millions of times, for example in a library.

Answer (score 2):

Depending in the type of `x`, the first form might not even compile (if the type has no copy-constructor).

I would probably go for:

```
the_type& x = obj.mem;
x.do1();
x.do2();
```

Note that accessing members from the outside is a very bad idea. It goes against one of the basic principles of object-oriented programming: *encapsulation*. Here is what you really should be doing:

```
obj.do_stuff();
```

Of course, it is hard to give any more advice without knowing what `do1`, `do2` and `mem` actually are.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is absolutely minimal, and neglectable.

Comment: If there is a difference, it might not be neglectable for every use case. Please elaborate.

Comment: There is a difference and it definitely isn't neglectable.